# Get latest row from DB for a particular column

Tags: java, sqlite, arraylist, collections, android-sqlite

From DB

```
+-----+---------+---------+
|user |  place  |timestamp|
+-------------------------+
|Name3|Location2|11:12    |
|Name1|Location1|11:13    |
|Name2|Location2|11:15    |
|Name3|Location3|11:16    |
|Name1|Location2|11:17    |
|Name4|Location1|11:18    |
+-----+---------+---------+
```

I want to query last entry for particular `user`, for example query for `Name3` should return `Location2`.

Is it possible to do it by sqlite query? Maybe it's easier to take all data to a [List](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/List.html) and then try to find last entry for particular `user`?

Comment: You need the most recent entry or the first entry for each user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following query in `Sqlite`:

```
select user, location from demo where timestamp in(
   select min(timestamp) from demo group by user) 
   order by user;
```

You can see the [demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/91c0e/7) here

Answer (score 2):

Use this query :
select * from (select * from table order by timestamp desc ) e group by e.user;

Comment: (there's also time stamp column not presented in the table)

Comment: their is any column in your table which will give the information about when the particular row is created??

Comment: select * from (select * from table order by timestamp desc ) e group by e.user;

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by running a raw query:

```
select place from table where timestamp = (select max(timestamp) from table);
```

Comment: but I want this also for other users